# Sock-puppet users answering/accepting their own questions

Tags: discussion

The user [srija](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/38503/srija) has posted three answers this morning to questions posted by [Ramesh M](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/13683/ramesh-m).

All three answers were instantly accepted, despite being very low quality. Two of the questions were from 2016; a [third](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209754/too-many-callouts-101-while-batch-calss-running#comment316315_209754) was asked this morning and answered one minute later; the question was incoherent and appeared to be designed to be "answered" in exactly the same way as one of the [older two](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136411/apex-cpu-time-limit-exceeded-error-in-batch-class). One of the answers was copied and pasted from a comment on the same question posted by cropredy. (Subsequent to my comment on this answer, the user edited the answer to replace the copy-paste with a link-only answer).

These users appear to be sock puppeting or coordinating with one another in an attempt to boost reputation. What is the best way to address this pattern of behavior? Should I/we simply flag all involved questions and answers?

Edit: additionally, questions asked by "srija" are answered/accepted by "Ramesh M" three times in a single day, January 29.

- [Error: Compile Error: Constructor not defined:](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/206150/error-compile-error-constructor-not-defined/206172#206172)
- [How to get admin using getting the contact id and accountId](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/206163/how-to-get-admin-using-getting-the-contact-id-and-accountid/206166#206166)
- [how to query user in test class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/206147/how-to-query-user-in-test-class/206162#206162)

Comment: yup, i flagged the last one, maybe the mods will spot something we cant with the mod tools

Comment: Oh, good, and here I just thought I was going crazy for a moment :p

Comment: I don't know what benefits someone will get by faking high SO creds:/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a whole bunch accounts that use the same IP, and one of the others has been marked as a potential sock puppet before. Same IP isn't a bad indicator in itself, but when there's screwy behaviour between a few accounts on there then something is up for sure.

I've raised it with the community team at SE who have the tools to really work out what's going on. For now if you see any more such answers please flag them (as you have been doing) and I'll keep hitting the delete button :)

## Update:

This has been handled by a member of the SE community team, and plenty of votes have been invalidated accordingly.